# Previously working Python NumPy.f2py fails with the latest Intel API Fortran

Tags: python, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran, f2py

When I try to rerun a previously successful instance of F2PY using Intel Fortran I receive an error message after it starts the compile.
Previously (Apr 2022) on Windows 10 I opened an existing available Intel Fortran command line with the result as shown on the attached image. The process described below worked with no problem.  The resulting PYD file has been successfully integrated into my Python code

Now, using Windows 11, I open a command line from the Intel oneAPI Fortran in 64bit with the following result

```
initializing oneAPI environment...
   Initializing Visual Studio command-line environment...
   Visual Studio version 16.11.20 environment configured.
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\"
   Visual Studio command-line environment initialized for: 'x64'
:  advisor -- latest
:  compiler -- latest
:  dal -- latest
:  debugger -- latest
:  dev-utilities -- latest
:  dnnl -- latest
:  dpcpp-ct -- latest
:  dpl -- latest
:  inspector -- latest
:  intelpython -- latest
:  ipp -- latest
:  ippcp -- latest
:  itac -- latest
:  mkl -- latest
:  mpi -- latest
:  tbb -- latest
:  vpl -- latest
:  vtune -- latest
:: oneAPI environment initialized ::
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI>
```

I changed directories to the location of the testcase and execute as follows

```
Python  -m numpy.f2py  -c test3.f  -m test3
```

The modules successfully creates the wrapper functions, finds and goes into compilation using the intel compiler, but fails with a long series traceback information that ultimately shows an error as follows

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I am at a loss as to how to move forward, my approach appears to match the instructions given online for F2PY

I have saved a complete set of  screen messages

The full series of the traceback message is shown below.

```
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\windows\bin\intel64\ifort.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 690, in main
    run_compile()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 657, in run_compile
    setup(ext_modules=[ext])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 61, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 271, in run
    self._f77_compiler = new_fcompiler(compiler=self.fcompiler,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\__init__.py", line 878, in new_fcompiler
    compiler = get_default_fcompiler(plat, requiref90=requiref90,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\__init__.py", line 849, in get_default_fcompiler
    compiler_type =  _find_existing_fcompiler(matching_compiler_types,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\__init__.py", line 801, in _find_existing_fcompiler
    v = c.get_version()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\intelpython\latest\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\intel.py", line 38, in get_version
    version = re.search(r'Version\s*([\d.]+)', output).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I expected a PYD file and am at a loss as to what needs to be changed.  I looked at the wrapper files in temporary data and these seemed to make sense

Here is fib1.f which leads to the same error

```
C FILE: FIB1.F
      SUBROUTINE FIB(A,N)
C
C     CALCULATE FIRST N FIBONACCI NUMBERS
C
      INTEGER N
      REAL*8 A(N)
      DO I=1,N
         IF (I.EQ.1) THEN
            A(I) = 0.0D0
         ELSEIF (I.EQ.2) THEN
            A(I) = 1.0D0
         ELSE 
            A(I) = A(I-1) + A(I-2)
         ENDIF
      ENDDO
      END
C END FILE FIB1.F
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. I fear that the code that causes the error will be necessary. See [ask] and [mcve]. The version of Python you are using will also be important.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I should stress that the subroutine block I used worked one year ago.  I have now tested a simple fairly standard source ()fb1.f) with the same rsulting error message.  I am using python 3.9.12 distributed by Intel